# Creating Index After the Fact SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, indexing, sqlalchemy, webmin

I have an SQL database that I am querying using SQLAlchemy. When I filter a query by a numeric column it returns the result fairly quickly. For example:

```
result = session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.myinteger == 1).all()
```

Note that this is not the primary id for the class, but just one variable of many. However, when I try to filter a query by column that consists of a 10 character string, it takes at least an order of magnitude longer to return the query. For example, the query would look something like this:

```
result = session.query(MyObject).filter(MyObject.mystring == 'Q1213W3239').all()
```

One option that could speed up the process would be to index the mystring column. I am unsure, however, how this interacts with SQLAlchemy. I believe that if I create an index of the mystring in the database, say using webmin (which is what I use to administer the database), then the database will automatically use the index for queries that filter on the variable. Is this correct or do I have to somehow let either SQLAlchemy know about the index or tell the database via SQLAlchemy to use that index?

Comment: Indexes don't speed things up until you get > 100K rows or more. Check for another solution.

Comment: I have around a half million in the table.

Comment: What sql db you are using? Sybase or MSSQL? In most case these database engines can derive a query plan based on your SQL statement and pick the most appropriate index. I don't think there is anything you need to do on SQLAlchemy's end if you are using Sybase or MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you create the index in the database, using Webmin or another tool, SQLAlchemy will automatically find it.

It might not automatically use it, nor if the index is used, it might not be faster.  It depends on several factors.

See also: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/